# getting value and summation from relationship tables on django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have tow modules (classes) on python django like this sample bellow :

```
#first one
class Names(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Types)
    value = models.IntegerField()

#second one
class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

as you see, the class `Names` have relationship with class `Type` so how to make a formula to get the total number of names and the summation of values in every class of `type` to get result something like this for example :

```
type1_total_names = 4
type1_sum_val = 22
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will aggregate the data of type and sum that of value. You'll find the summation in `sum_value`

```
from django.db.models import Count

query = (Names.objects
              .values('type')
              .annotate(sum_value=Count('value'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To [query the related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) you can try the code below:

```
type_1_obj = Type.objects.get(pk=1)
type_1_total_names = type_obj.names_set.all().count()
type_1_sum_val = type_obj.names_set.all().aggregate(sum_val=Sum('value'))['sum_val']
```